# JQuery on dropdown list change is not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new to code igniter and I have searched the following question in number of StackOverflow threads but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I have the following view code:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
</select>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Ajax post
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select1").change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/mycontroller/method",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(res) {

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Ok when I change the drop down list selection nothing happens, which should actually call my controller method. Can you please help me resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: See browser console if any error is showing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `<select>` id as `category`

But In jquery you are calling `$("#select1").change(function(event)` like this .

You just need to change `$("#select1").change(function(event)` to

`$("#category").change(function(event)`

Comment: My bad actually the name and id fields have the same value of select1 and still the event wont fire up on change, Thanks for your reply !

Comment: What is the value for echo base_url();  ?

Comment: add a `/` before index.php "/index.php/mycontroller/method",

Comment: Actually your point of inspection helped me resolve the issue, its an issue with incorrect baseurl defined. Thanks !

Comment: No problem . Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake with your jquery selector.

you are using `$("#select1").change(function(){});`

you don't have any id reffered in this name in your section.

```
$("#category").change(function(event) { 

     //ur code here

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check in console if your script contains any errors.

if no errors with script, check your function getting called after change, by adding alert or console statement.

if function getting called, check base_url. As per latest comment '/' missing.

You can also try Following snippet :

```
//Add J Query Library here

<select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="funName(this);">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function funName(element)
 {
     var id = element.value;
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "/index.php/mycontroller/method",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"id" : id},
        success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
        }
    });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Actually this is another issue which I faced earlier, which generates funName not defined in my console browser although its defined in the select tag. What gives ?

Answer (score 0):

You used id selector in the jquery code but that id is mentioned as a name attribute in html dropdown tag. So try the following code.

Change this following:-

```
<select name="select1" id="category">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
</select>
<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Ajax post
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#category").change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/mycontroller/method",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(res) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually the name and id have the same value of select1 and still the event wont fire up on change. I just edited my question.